# How to set minimum and max times in an ion-datetime

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using an ionic DateTime component to pick just time in my page. But I have to just allow the user to select times from 06:30 Am to 07:30 PM. How can I limit the min-max times in ion-datetime

I have already tried giving min value to the component directly.

`<ion-datetime displayFormat="hh:mm a" min="minDate"></ion-datetime>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can specify them as props:

```js
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMMM YYYY" min="2016" max="2020-10-31" [(ngModel)]="myDate">
  </ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

check the ion-datetime [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/datetime/DateTime/) on `Min and Max Datetimes`
 section

Comment: The question was asking about time  06:30 Am to 07:30 PM not dates or years.

Answer (score 1):

try with this :

I have using pickerFormate (24 Hr Formate) and displayValue (12 Hr Formate). it's similar your logic.

Homepage.html

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Time</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime  [hourValues]="hourValues" [min]="minTime" [max]="maxTime" displayFormat="hh:mm A" pickerFormat="HH:mm A" (ionFocus)="changeDate($event)"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
```

Homepage.ts

```
myDate: String = new Date().toISOString();
  minTime = '06:30';
  maxTime = '19:30';
  hourValues = ['06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19'];
```

Result

[image]

Demo Link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-htjuyr-datepicker

Comment: In this way the user can only select time 6 :30 - 7:59 Am/pm. does not solve the purpose

Comment: This caused the AM/PM picker to disappear.

Comment: Yes, I am using 24 Hr Format only for pick, after pick show value with AM/PM.

Comment: is there a way to achieve it in a 12 hour format, like when the user selects the time of 08:30 the 'PM' selector is disabled (or hidden)?

Comment: I have tried with 12 Hr format, but ionic library create issue in time scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

html code

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="hh:mm a" [min]="minTime" [max]="maxTime"></ion-datetime>
```

ts code

```
 minTime = '06:30';
 maxTime = '07:30';
```

Comment: this way the user won't be able to select other times like 8:30 etc.

Comment: you can give hoursValue to date picker e.g. <ion-datetime displayFormat="hh:mm a" hourValues="07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19"></ion-datetime>

Answer (score 0):

I tried this approach to get my bug cracked after crushing 6-7 days. In my case, I have to pass the getMinimum value as the minimum time while checking out. So users should not be able to check-out before the check-in time.

**.ts File**

```
check_in_value: 2021-12-06T13:15:11.684Z
const a = parseISO(check_in_value);
const b = addHours(new Date(a),5);
this.getMinimum = b.toISOString()
concole.log(this.getMinimum)
```

**HTML File**

```
<ion-datetime
displayFormat="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
pickerFormat="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
[value]="check_out"
[min]="getMinimum3"
></ion-datetime>
```

**Important Notes:**

The Displaying Format plays an important factor in rendering the Date and Time. Read the documentation thoroughly. “Ionic Framework uses the ISO 8601 datetime format for its value”. Link: ion-datetime: Ionic API Input for Datetime Format Picker

“Exactly the components shown here must be present, with exactly this punctuation” Link: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime?_gl=1*1lg7t6u*_ga*MTk3MzQ4NzM5Ny4xNjQxODg2ODQy*_ga_REH9TJF6KF*MTY1MDMyNDM1MS4xMTIuMS4xNjUwMzI2NjU0LjA.

“Exactly the components shown here must be present, with exactly this punctuation” Link: https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve it without restricting users from selecting between 7:30AM to 6:30PM which will happen if you use the min and max attributes.

```
<ion-datetime hourCycle="h23"
[(ngModel)]="selectedDate" 
minuteValues="30" 
hourValues="06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19"></ion-datetime>
```